# Unable to populate data in DataTable from Controller in Codeingiter

Tags: ajax, codeigniter, datatable

I am trying to list data with DataTable using server side processing through ajax. I am getting the expected response from the controller when the ajax hits. But the data is still not populated in the dataTable.

**Controller**

```
 public function get_role_details() {
    $this->load_generic_model(array('mst_role_model'));

    $draw = intval($this->input->get("draw"));
    $start = intval($this->input->get("start"));
    $length = intval($this->input->get("length"));

    $selected_rol = array('m_role_id','m_role_name');
    $condition = array('m_role_status' => 'enable');
    $other_configs = array('order_by' => 'm_role_id', 'order_dir' => 'DESC');
    // $other_configs
    $get_role = $this->mst_role_model->get_where_selected( $selected_rol, $condition, $other_configs);

    if( (empty($get_role)) || !($get_role) )
    {
        echo json_encode(array('status' => 500, 'msg' => 'Server Error, Try again later'));
        return false;
    }
    $data['role'] = $get_role;
    $data['role_cnt'] = count($get_role);
    
    $json_data = json_encode(array('status' => 200, 'data' => $data));
    
    echo $json_data;
}
```

**View**

```
<section class="content">
    <div class="box">
        <div class="box-body">
            <table id="logTable1" class="table" width="100%">
                <thead>
                    <th>Role id</th>
                    <th>Role Name</th>
                </thead>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>

<script type="text/javascript"> 
    $(document).ready(function() { 
        $("#logTable1").DataTable({
            'processing': false,
            'serverSide': true,
            'ajax': {
                'url':'<?php echo base_url()."role/get_role_details"; ?>',
                'type' : 'POST'
            },
            'columns' : [
                {data : 'm_role_id'},
                {data : 'm_role_name'}
            ]
        });
    }); 
</script>
```

[image: output screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

I use something similar the following

```
$( document ).ready(function() { // when document is ready load
    $.ajax({ // create an AJAX call...
        type: $(this).attr('method'), // GET or POST
        url: "<?php echo base_url("controller/function/"); ?>", // the file to call
        success: function(response) { // on success..
            var dts=JSON.parse(response) // becomes your array 
            var dataSet =dts.result; 

// I specified the results in your case data to just call one filter then create the data table within the success call 
     
           $('#table_name').DataTable( {
                data: dataSet,
                fixedHeader: true,
                dom: 'Bfrtip',
                buttons: [
                    'copyHtml5',
                    'excelHtml5',
                    'csvHtml5',
                    'pdfHtml5',
                ],
                columns: [
                    { title: "Who",
                        data: "username",
                        defaultContent: ""
                    },
                    {
                        title: "Accepted",
                        data: "accepted_when",
                        render: function ( data, type, row ) {
                            var rowgpd = moment(data).format("Do MMM YYYY HH:mm:ss");
                            return rowgpd;
                        }},
                    { title: "Status",
                        data: "status",
                        defaultContent: ""
                    },
                ]
            } );

        }
    });
    return false; // cancel original event to prevent form submitting
});
```

I believe it will do exactly as you want.
Its pretty straight forward I think .
So for me I had to parse the response to remove the json encoding and allow me to call the row and columns from the array. I also use moment js to parse the date and display in a better format.

Answer (score 0):

> Data array location DataTables requires an array of items to represent
> the table's data, where each item in the array is a row. The item is
> typically an object or an array (discussed in more detail below) - so
> the first thing we need to do is tell DataTables where that array is
> in the data source.

https://datatables.net/manual/ajax

Answer (score 0):

Based on your screenshot, your JSON response appears to be this:

```js
{
    "data": {
        "role": [{
            "m_role_id": "47",
            "m_role_name": "Aakash"
        }, {
            "m_role_id": "46",
            "m_role_name": "Visiting Doctor"
        }]
    }
}
```

This is valid JSON, and it may be what you are expecting. But it is not what DataTables is expecting, when you are using DataTables with `'serverSide': true`.

There are two problems:

1. You need to tell DataTables where the array (containing your row data) is located in your JSON - which in your case is `data.role`. Normally, you would do this using the [`dataSrc`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax.dataSrc) option:

```js
'ajax': {
  'url':'<?php echo base_url()."role/get_role_details"; ?>',
  'type' : 'POST',
  'dataSrc': 'data.role'
},
```

2. Because you are using server-side processing, your JSON response should use the structure shown in the  [server-side documentation](https://datatables.net/manual/server-side#Example-data):

```js
{
    "draw": 1,
    "recordsTotal": 57,
    "recordsFiltered": 57,
    "data": [{
        "m_role_id": "47",
        "m_role_name": "Aakash"
    }, {
        "m_role_id": "46",
        "m_role_name": "Visiting Doctor"
    }]
}
```

Note the following:

- The JSON needs to include those [extra fields](https://datatables.net/manual/server-side#Returned-data) such as `recordsTotal`, to ensure pagination controls and information are displayed correctly.
- The `[ ... ]` array is now directly attached to `data` in your JSON. There is no intermediate `role` object.

You can still keep `role` if you want to, but then you do still need to use `dataSrc`, as described above.

I recommend you follow the structure in the documentation, for simplicity.